# How can I horizontally center an element with siblings, and retain the flow?

Tags: html, css

Current Render: https://i.stack.imgur.com/onSBo.png
Desired Render: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vElqt.png

Hello,

In the example below, I would like my logo element (id="logo") to appear between my 3rd and 4th li element. That is, I want to make it appear exactly in the center of its parent, but still reside in the normal flow with its siblings.

**I cannot simply place the logo element in the correct position, because the li elements are automatically generated and are of an unknown amount.**

A CSS-only solution would be preferable, if possible.

Thanks!

```
<style type="text/css">
ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
}

#logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}
</style>
<ul>
    <li>Nav 1</li>
    <li>Nav 2</li>
    <li>Nav 3</li>
    <li>Nav 4</li>
    <li>Nav 5</li>
    <li>Nav 6</li>
    <li id="logo"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you have id attribute on the other li elements?

Comment: flexbox would be the natural candidate but it's not compatible with IE9- and Opera Mini http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: which IE version you want to support? javascript is consider an option for you?

Comment: @Aboodred1 Yes, I'm using WordPress and generating the items from a nav menu, which automatically adds IDs like "menu-item-86" for the 86th menu item.

Comment: @FelipeAls Yes, Flexbox *could* do it, but it requires certain known quantities first, and it sounds like the OP cannot guarantee them.  You have to know how many elements there are in advance so that the logo can be shifted to the middle position (either by modifying the source order or modifying the `order` on the last set of elements).

Comment: @Aboodred1 I would consider using JavaScript if you know of a solution. Although an all CSS solution would be preferable.

Comment: @cimmanon True, you still've to know where begins the second half of your items (minus the last one)

Comment: Why is your logo one of the list items in what is presumably a nav menu? Simplest solution would be to save the logo as an image and make it the background image of the ul. You can then add a class to half of the li's and float them left, and another class to the remaining li's and float them right.

Comment: @BrianO'Neill The half of an unknown quantity is unknown. So after playing with http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vInuo , +1 for JS and reordering the list as it'll be displayed: can then be simply styled in CSS and also will be more accessible (see [WCAG 2.0 Technique C27](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20120103/C27))

Comment: @BrianO'Neill Technically my logo is also a navigational item, because it is a link and represents "home". I am currently using a solution where I've done exactly what you're saying, by limiting the number of elements to 6 and floating 3 to each side. I'm looking for a way to remove that restriction, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As CSS solution you can do it like the following code:

Note: you need to add different id attribute for each li element

```
<style type="text/css">
ul {
    display: block;
    width: 700px;
    overflow: hidden;
    zoom: 1;
}

li {
  width: 100px;
}

li#menu-item-80,
li#menu-item-81,
li#menu-item-82,
li#logo {
    float: left;
}

li#menu-item-83,
li#menu-item-84,
li#menu-item-85 {
    float: right;
}


#logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}
</style>
<ul>
    <li id="menu-item-80">Nav 1</li>
    <li id="menu-item-81">Nav 2</li>
    <li id="menu-item-82">Nav 3</li>
    <li id="menu-item-83">Nav 4</li>
    <li id="menu-item-84">Nav 5</li>
    <li id="menu-item-85">Nav 6</li>
    <li id="logo"></li>
</ul>
```

As Javascript jQuery solution, you can reorder menu items by appending the last item after the third item as the following jQuery code

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('ul li:eq(2)').after($('li#logo'));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually already have an implementation similar to this, where I've restricted the number of list items and floated each half away from the center.

I'm looking to remove that restriction and allow an unknown number of items, for which this would no longer be valid.

Comment: I will post jquery javascript solution, but it will reorder the menu to make it work with you current style

Comment: @Gleasonator added jQuery solution